# How can I optimize my code for better execution times

Tags: opencv, image-processing, kotlin

I'm implementing an image processing algorithm called BM3D and I've already achieved the outcome which is denoising a grayscale image but the thing is that it is too slow, even with a 436 by 436 gray image.

I have already tried to find way to maybe fasten up the work that I do with array and lists, but didn't get much improvement

```
val img = imread("files/image.png", 0)
val img3= Mat(img.rows(),img.cols(),img.type())

val listaBlocos = mutableListOf(Pair(0.0, Pair(0,0)))
val tamanhoBloco = 3 //Block Size
val tamanhoJanela = 9 //Window Size
val mediaPorBloco = DoubleArray(16)
var sum = 0.0
listaBlocos.clear()
val stats_file = File("files/tempos436x436.txt")
val test = 10
for (x in 0 until test){
    val timeelapsed = measureTimeMillis {
        for (col in 20 ..img.width() - 20) {
            for (row in 20 ..img.height() - 20) {
                val block1 = generateBlock(img, row, col, tamanhoBloco)
                for (c in -tamanhoJanela..tamanhoJanela) {
                    for (l in -tamanhoJanela..tamanhoJanela) {
                        val  block2 = generateBlock(img, row + l, col + c, tamanhoBloco)
                        val  d = distBlock(block1, block2)
                        val  par = Pair(d, Pair(row + l, col + c))
                        listaBlocos.add(par)
                    }
                }
                val listaBlocosOrdenada = listaBlocos.sortedWith(compareBy { it.first })
                listaBlocos.clear()
                for (k in 0..15) {
                    sum = 0.0
                    val c2 = listaBlocosOrdenada[k].second.second
                    val l2 = listaBlocosOrdenada[k].second.first

                    for (c in 0..tamanhoBloco - 1) {
                        for (l in 0..tamanhoBloco - 1) {
                            sum += img.get(l2 - l, c2 - c)[0]
                        }
                    }
                    mediaPorBloco[k] = sum / 4
                }
                val v = mediaPorBloco.average()
                img3.put(row,col,v)

            }
        }
    }
imwrite("files/resultado.png", img3)
stats_file.appendText("teste$x 100X200 $timeelapsed\n")

}
```

well the result in the actual image denoising is good but is takes maybe 15 min to denoise a 436 x 436 image. I'm currently using a virtual machine with Ubuntu and 4 cores a 4 gbs of Ram

Comment: Getting better and more efficient compiler is the most easiest way. But if you aim sth higher. How about changing from object-oriented/ java like programming style and use C++ with SSE/NEON instruction set on all of those math methods?? this should give you top speed?

Comment: See here for detailed sample http://sci.tuomastonteri.fi/programming/sse .  BM3D 15 min on 436 X 436 is a bit bad.  Now a lot of deep learning based method can run faster than that.

Comment: Yeah you're right but the thing is i really have to use kotlin, and have implement the algorithm, there are other parameters to lower the execution time such as the blocksize or windowsize but it will denoise very badly

Comment: For you code given , I dont forsee any means of effective improvement.   but for things like distBlock  try some    SSE based library if possible.

Comment: There are no obvious performance improvements to be made, assuming the compiler optimizes things like range expressions and object creation. You need to run a profiler and see where time is being spent

Comment: Well i decided to use use threads to devide the workload, is it a good choice ?

Comment: I don't know how Kotlin lays out images in memory, but you may find your caching performance is better if you loop over the rows first and then over the columns within that block rather than the other way around.

Comment: ok, i'll look into that, i've also made a huge improvement, just by converting the Mat to a 2D Array and then do the actual work on thoose arrays, i think i've gained a 70% perfomance boost just by doing this,it still needs some more testing though

Comment: Thank you all for the answers

Comment: i think i've solved it guys, i change the search algorithm to a faster one also and now i can process the image in maybe half a second